# Tools to enhance, analyse our site, etc

Tags: discussion, tools

In order to make our site better we need to have some quick overview about some important aspects. For this purpose I wrote three small applications that do the following:

1. Analyze all tags that we have and list those that haven't yet a wiki excerpt. This should alleviate the search for tags that have to taken be care of. The application is available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17805353/TagExtractor.jar).
2. Stack Exchange lists some hot questions over all sites. If one of our questions is listed there, it generates a lot of attention for our site. To keep an overview about the questions that are currently in the hot list, I wrote [this application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17805353/HotQuestionsExtractor.jar).
3. Statistics are important to see the progress of the site. Unfortunately the default statistics doesn't provide a lot of insights. Therefore I wrote [this application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17805353/ViewsExtractor.jar) that retrieves all possible stats from the API and also stores it in a `CSV` file so that it can be used later to make charts or similar things.

My question now is: Are these applications useful? What else do we need to know?

To show how it could look like, I generated two charts for the last days. The scale is unfortunately not linear, but you can get an impression:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice with the graphs. [I went and asked on webapps if there's an online service that will plot for us](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20632/is-there-a-free-webapp-service-to-plot-data-with-a-nonlinear-x-axis) even with a nonlinear X axis, maybe even combine them into a single graph.

Comment: Have you looked at Google Charts? It's very easy to pipe data into that and get dynamic graphs back as a result...

Comment: @Mark : I was trying to find an easier way out that programming since I don't have much experience with that kind of thing. I was hoping there'd be some webapp like Google Docs spreadsheet or Wolfram Alpha that could do it from a data processing angle rather than a coding angle. But seems programming is unavoidable.

Comment: how about an update on the above graph? ;)

Comment: @Mark: I implemented a Google Charts solution that you paste the output of Roflcopter's tool into: **[Tool to visualize stats of travel.stackexchange.com over time](https://gist.github.com/1608753)**

Comment: See also: **[Handy Travel-SE links and tools](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/879)**

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea for a tool using the API.

**A chatbot for "You Are Here"** that can look up nifty factoids from various mashup data providers, do googlefights, get definitions of words from Wiktionary, stuff like that.

I've worked on an IRC chatbot before with some of those features.

I've asked about them on meta and while SE doesn't provide much to help create them, they are not prohibited and three have been created already: [Coding Kitten, FlackBot, and Eliza](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116698/154292).

Comment: I'd really like to do this. Maybe if I have time over Christmas we can start a small project.

Comment: Well I'm off 50% of the time and until my lost wallet problems are resolved I have no money to go out anyway so I can surely join in the fun! (-:

Answer (score 4):

Another idea for a tool using the API.

**Tag wiki watchlist**

Get notification when tags you have shown interest in (by creating, favouriting, or editing at some point) have been modified by editing, renaming, adding or removing synonyms, deleting, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with the API.

Comment: There is no specific support but everything you need is there. It provides enumeration of tags and synonyms and access to current tag wiki and excerpt text. The tool would have to keep track of everything else itself.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea for a tool using the API.

**List the oldest single-use tags**

Would be very useful for [the event idea I suggested the other day](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/topic-challenge-call-for-topics).

Comment: That shouldn't be a lot of work. We can easily use an already existing tool to find the single usage tags. And then we just have to get the linked question, parse the date and then sort it.

Comment: Done. Added a list as an answer to this question

Comment: Hehe I don't know if we need the output here right now. It's pretty bulky and it will change. A link to the code on github or something might be nice though.

Answer (score 3):

Awesome work!

Does everybody know how to run a Java app? I don't (-:

It would be great if they could be hosted somewhere so we could access them on a web page.

I'm thinking of making pure JavaScript versions of the first two, the third requires writing to the filesystem or somewhere so is a bit complicated for JavaScript.

Comment: If you have installed Java on your computer you can run it like this: Go to the terminal/console and navigate to the folder in which the jar file is located. The execute this command: java -jar TheApplicationName.jar

Comment: Double-clicking a JAR should work too.

Comment: Hmm double-clicking doesn't seem to do anything for me here on Win 7 Starter but running from a dos box did work.

Comment: you should have a JRE installed. Search "JRE download" current version should be 7. but 6 is ok though. You can host java app freely in the Google App Engine. I can help.

Answer (score 2):

**Airport tag checker**

This tool will find all 3-letter tags.

Then it will look them all up on an airport code mashup service.

It will report the following anomolies:

- 3-letter tags which are not IATA airport codes
- 3-letter tags which do not have wiki excerpts

When that works I will try to get it to compare the definitions from the service against the definitions in the tag excerpts, but that will be a bit trickier.

It will be a single HTML file that will run on any browser and can be included in any site.

Comment: We already have that. I implemented it some weeks ago.

Comment: I know. I just want to make my own version and it will be a web page anyone with a browser can use. It's partly to get back in the practice of coding again plus an excuse to learn jQuery, CORS, and YQL at least.

Comment: You can now download and try my **[Tool to analyse IATA airport code tags on travel.stackexchange.com](https://gist.github.com/1513820)** gist from github. It's just a single HTML file which should run in all modern browsers. It won't run in older versions of some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make this an answer since it is way to long for a comment. I just wrote a little query to get all our single usage tags sorted by date. This is one of the tools, hippietrail suggested. Hope it helps:

```
amazon-jungle: Tue Jun 21 22:22:33 CEST 2011
sin: Tue Jun 21 22:24:57 CEST 2011
singapore-airlines: Tue Jun 21 22:24:57 CEST 2011
redmond: Tue Jun 21 22:30:38 CEST 2011
permit: Tue Jun 21 23:33:35 CEST 2011
johannesburg: Tue Jun 21 23:48:16 CEST 2011
tel-aviv: Wed Jun 22 00:01:50 CEST 2011
alsace: Wed Jun 22 00:02:40 CEST 2011
texas: Wed Jun 22 00:08:57 CEST 2011
sapa: Wed Jun 22 00:11:42 CEST 2011
ha-long-bay: Wed Jun 22 00:11:42 CEST 2011
darien-gap: Wed Jun 22 00:18:38 CEST 2011
panama: Wed Jun 22 00:18:38 CEST 2011
colombia: Wed Jun 22 00:18:38 CEST 2011
sq: Wed Jun 22 00:26:39 CEST 2011
volgograd: Wed Jun 22 07:48:59 CEST 2011
turin: Wed Jun 22 08:19:17 CEST 2011
maldives: Wed Jun 22 13:51:17 CEST 2011
peking: Wed Jun 22 16:18:06 CEST 2011
fishing: Wed Jun 22 18:45:51 CEST 2011
atyrau: Thu Jun 23 06:51:20 CEST 2011
burma: Thu Jun 23 11:51:22 CEST 2011
mayan: Thu Jun 23 20:13:49 CEST 2011
lake-atitlan: Thu Jun 23 20:13:49 CEST 2011
ist: Thu Jun 23 21:00:48 CEST 2011
translation: Thu Jun 23 21:01:03 CEST 2011
machu-pichu: Fri Jun 24 00:52:47 CEST 2011
reference: Fri Jun 24 07:17:50 CEST 2011
sentos: Sat Jun 25 21:33:13 CEST 2011
saint-petersburg: Mon Jun 27 04:55:45 CEST 2011
penang: Mon Jun 27 22:42:16 CEST 2011
st-louis: Tue Jun 28 23:06:14 CEST 2011
missouri: Tue Jun 28 23:06:14 CEST 2011
yyz: Wed Jun 29 15:42:02 CEST 2011
khiva: Thu Jun 30 17:55:05 CEST 2011
warsaw: Fri Jul 01 10:45:17 CEST 2011
ltn: Fri Jul 01 10:45:17 CEST 2011
alberta: Fri Jul 01 19:49:16 CEST 2011
british-columbia: Fri Jul 01 19:49:16 CEST 2011
oslo: Fri Jul 01 23:17:24 CEST 2011
northern-cyprus: Mon Jul 04 07:52:20 CEST 2011
banff: Tue Jul 05 19:37:21 CEST 2011
calgary: Tue Jul 05 19:37:21 CEST 2011
chateaux: Tue Jul 05 23:19:11 CEST 2011
khojand: Fri Jul 08 16:14:06 CEST 2011
guangzhou: Sun Jul 10 09:33:25 CEST 2011
crimea: Mon Jul 11 11:24:34 CEST 2011
ryanair: Tue Jul 12 08:25:25 CEST 2011
louvre: Tue Jul 12 23:17:14 CEST 2011
chengdu: Sat Jul 16 13:00:21 CEST 2011
road-atlas: Sun Jul 17 10:58:42 CEST 2011
politics: Sun Jul 17 12:47:57 CEST 2011
south-east-asia: Mon Jul 18 07:56:24 CEST 2011
angkor-wat: Mon Jul 18 07:56:24 CEST 2011
siem-reap: Mon Jul 18 07:56:24 CEST 2011
abkhazia: Mon Jul 18 11:28:52 CEST 2011
south-ossetia: Mon Jul 18 11:36:53 CEST 2011
bern: Mon Jul 18 18:38:41 CEST 2011
elm-switzerland: Mon Jul 18 18:38:41 CEST 2011
mountain-biking: Tue Jul 19 14:28:12 CEST 2011
green-card: Wed Jul 20 08:45:36 CEST 2011
uln: Wed Jul 20 09:47:40 CEST 2011
playa-del-carmen: Wed Jul 20 14:54:54 CEST 2011
iguazu: Thu Jul 21 05:27:16 CEST 2011
balykchy: Thu Jul 21 18:29:23 CEST 2011
issyk-kul: Thu Jul 21 18:29:23 CEST 2011
madrid: Sun Jul 24 17:54:22 CEST 2011
talgo: Wed Jul 27 18:11:55 CEST 2011
victoria-falls: Thu Jul 28 13:25:44 CEST 2011
tse: Fri Jul 29 12:04:04 CEST 2011
seville: Fri Jul 29 15:50:57 CEST 2011
palau: Fri Jul 29 22:11:32 CEST 2011
hannover: Sat Jul 30 00:16:20 CEST 2011
freiburg: Sat Jul 30 00:16:20 CEST 2011
dolomites: Wed Aug 03 22:35:54 CEST 2011
moscow: Fri Aug 05 16:52:27 CEST 2011
reykjavik: Sat Aug 06 19:37:20 CEST 2011
bsl: Sat Aug 06 20:02:37 CEST 2011
congo: Sat Aug 06 23:51:14 CEST 2011
rwanda: Sat Aug 06 23:51:14 CEST 2011
petra: Sun Aug 07 17:54:16 CEST 2011
edinburgh: Wed Aug 10 00:22:40 CEST 2011
dead-sea: Wed Aug 10 10:39:03 CEST 2011
kuwait: Wed Aug 10 13:25:20 CEST 2011
montreal: Fri Aug 12 09:30:21 CEST 2011
pakistan-citizens: Sat Aug 13 09:40:28 CEST 2011
terelj: Sun Aug 14 12:50:38 CEST 2011
nile: Tue Aug 16 18:48:41 CEST 2011
rice-terrace: Wed Aug 17 22:18:56 CEST 2011
nova-scotia: Fri Aug 19 03:42:38 CEST 2011
us-airways: Sun Aug 21 05:01:44 CEST 2011
kosovo: Sun Aug 21 09:43:00 CEST 2011
bucharest: Mon Aug 22 06:28:29 CEST 2011
constanta: Mon Aug 22 06:28:29 CEST 2011
china-airlines: Mon Aug 22 11:45:40 CEST 2011
montenegro: Mon Aug 22 21:04:18 CEST 2011
hunting: Tue Aug 23 03:59:01 CEST 2011
sustainable: Tue Aug 23 03:59:01 CEST 2011
korean-air: Tue Aug 23 19:13:57 CEST 2011
delta-air-lines: Tue Aug 23 19:13:57 CEST 2011
timor-leste: Thu Aug 25 10:38:15 CEST 2011
belfast: Thu Aug 25 11:05:22 CEST 2011
airbnb: Sat Aug 27 17:42:26 CEST 2011
horseriding: Sat Aug 27 21:46:46 CEST 2011
travel-sickness: Mon Aug 29 15:17:01 CEST 2011
hua-hin: Thu Sep 01 01:50:05 CEST 2011
bkk: Thu Sep 01 01:50:05 CEST 2011
indonesia-citizens: Thu Sep 01 04:55:51 CEST 2011
croatia: Thu Sep 01 20:12:08 CEST 2011
zadar: Thu Sep 01 20:12:08 CEST 2011
split: Thu Sep 01 20:12:08 CEST 2011
volunteering: Fri Sep 02 14:04:06 CEST 2011
batumi: Fri Sep 02 17:45:19 CEST 2011
plovdiv: Sun Sep 04 10:22:05 CEST 2011
maui: Tue Sep 06 15:21:16 CEST 2011
lahaina: Tue Sep 06 15:21:16 CEST 2011
oneworld: Tue Sep 06 22:49:50 CEST 2011
kopaonik: Sun Sep 11 22:58:16 CEST 2011
munich: Thu Sep 15 15:07:13 CEST 2011
oktoberfest: Thu Sep 15 15:07:13 CEST 2011
parabolic-flight: Thu Sep 15 22:32:19 CEST 2011
yamanashi: Fri Sep 16 07:16:00 CEST 2011
space: Fri Sep 16 10:14:50 CEST 2011
air-france: Fri Sep 16 17:56:59 CEST 2011
iraq: Fri Sep 16 18:30:24 CEST 2011
hel: Sat Sep 17 10:25:48 CEST 2011
cgn: Sat Sep 17 11:15:49 CEST 2011
cologne: Sat Sep 17 11:15:49 CEST 2011
annapurna: Sat Sep 17 13:21:48 CEST 2011
tilicho-lake: Sat Sep 17 13:21:48 CEST 2011
cdg: Mon Sep 19 08:19:30 CEST 2011
north-pole: Tue Sep 20 03:09:44 CEST 2011
tesol: Tue Sep 20 16:03:19 CEST 2011
kerala: Tue Sep 20 17:25:51 CEST 2011
kochi: Tue Sep 20 17:25:51 CEST 2011
qantas: Wed Sep 21 01:28:00 CEST 2011
san: Wed Sep 21 13:43:40 CEST 2011
southwest-airlines: Thu Sep 22 07:02:35 CEST 2011
chernobyl: Thu Sep 22 15:14:31 CEST 2011
homestay: Fri Sep 23 14:14:41 CEST 2011
maori: Fri Sep 23 14:14:41 CEST 2011
torres-strait: Fri Sep 23 15:07:53 CEST 2011
aboriginal: Fri Sep 23 15:07:53 CEST 2011
eurostar: Sat Sep 24 06:51:42 CEST 2011
dxb: Mon Sep 26 02:57:37 CEST 2011
trans-pacific: Mon Sep 26 04:48:40 CEST 2011
antipodes: Mon Sep 26 04:48:40 CEST 2011
nagorno-karabakh: Mon Sep 26 09:22:19 CEST 2011
mount-rainier: Mon Sep 26 20:30:34 CEST 2011
atlanta: Wed Sep 28 00:08:28 CEST 2011
georgia-usa: Wed Sep 28 00:08:28 CEST 2011
jat-airways: Thu Sep 29 09:33:23 CEST 2011
czech-republic: Thu Sep 29 16:14:46 CEST 2011
durres: Fri Sep 30 17:42:29 CEST 2011
safari: Sun Oct 02 22:58:56 CEST 2011
sarande: Sun Oct 02 23:44:42 CEST 2011
gjirokaster: Sun Oct 02 23:44:42 CEST 2011
aerosvit: Mon Oct 03 23:56:25 CEST 2011
swiss: Mon Oct 03 23:56:25 CEST 2011
airbaltic: Mon Oct 03 23:56:25 CEST 2011
veliko-tarnovo: Thu Oct 06 11:13:02 CEST 2011
corfu: Mon Oct 10 10:48:57 CEST 2011
suriname: Tue Oct 11 18:01:03 CEST 2011
french-guiana: Tue Oct 11 18:01:03 CEST 2011
liverpool: Wed Oct 12 20:06:11 CEST 2011
great-lakes: Thu Oct 13 21:10:46 CEST 2011
cairo: Fri Oct 14 08:51:56 CEST 2011
november: Sat Oct 15 15:02:17 CEST 2011
pamplona: Sun Oct 16 01:43:28 CEST 2011
san-fermin: Sun Oct 16 01:43:28 CEST 2011
mount-everest: Mon Oct 17 09:16:44 CEST 2011
vienna: Wed Oct 19 20:27:32 CEST 2011
namibia: Wed Oct 19 23:22:20 CEST 2011
kruger: Wed Oct 19 23:22:20 CEST 2011
garden-route: Wed Oct 19 23:22:20 CEST 2011
chand-baori: Thu Oct 20 21:59:58 CEST 2011
stepwells: Thu Oct 20 21:59:58 CEST 2011
travel-restrictions: Fri Oct 21 13:45:13 CEST 2011
air-new-zealand: Fri Oct 21 13:45:13 CEST 2011
boarding: Fri Oct 21 15:07:58 CEST 2011
lufthansa: Fri Oct 21 23:04:20 CEST 2011
nakhchivan: Sat Oct 22 17:31:59 CEST 2011
kyoto: Sun Oct 23 21:23:00 CEST 2011
baltics: Sun Oct 23 22:39:42 CEST 2011
auschwitz: Mon Oct 24 00:05:59 CEST 2011
skovde: Mon Oct 24 23:09:45 CEST 2011
canaima-national-park: Wed Oct 26 01:23:36 CEST 2011
angel-falls: Wed Oct 26 01:23:36 CEST 2011
yosemite: Wed Oct 26 08:51:29 CEST 2011
pdx: Wed Oct 26 17:30:46 CEST 2011
english: Wed Oct 26 23:11:09 CEST 2011
dreamliner: Thu Oct 27 08:14:34 CEST 2011
code-sharing: Fri Oct 28 00:28:12 CEST 2011
sinistrality: Fri Oct 28 13:25:54 CEST 2011
great-barrier-reef: Sun Oct 30 09:39:22 CET 2011
exclaves: Tue Nov 01 15:55:56 CET 2011
falkland-islands: Tue Nov 01 22:59:54 CET 2011
exploration: Wed Nov 02 05:04:02 CET 2011
sovereign-territories: Wed Nov 02 05:13:03 CET 2011
foreign-dependencies: Wed Nov 02 05:13:03 CET 2011
great-plains: Wed Nov 02 18:35:41 CET 2011
dublin: Thu Nov 03 19:50:47 CET 2011
galleries: Thu Nov 03 22:41:55 CET 2011
ports: Fri Nov 04 00:23:34 CET 2011
telavi: Fri Nov 04 14:08:57 CET 2011
kakheti: Fri Nov 04 14:08:57 CET 2011
okinawa: Sat Nov 05 16:47:14 CET 2011
loch-ness: Sat Nov 05 18:57:13 CET 2011
adak-island: Sun Nov 06 01:18:40 CET 2011
airships: Mon Nov 07 10:31:45 CET 2011
zeppelins: Mon Nov 07 10:31:45 CET 2011
italy-citizens: Mon Nov 07 22:35:56 CET 2011
scandinavian-airlines: Tue Nov 08 12:00:46 CET 2011
truecrypt: Tue Nov 08 18:58:40 CET 2011
exhibitions: Wed Nov 09 21:38:27 CET 2011
ramadan: Thu Nov 10 13:59:32 CET 2011
visa-free-entry: Thu Nov 10 14:40:44 CET 2011
berlin: Sun Nov 13 00:04:11 CET 2011
jeju: Sun Nov 13 05:44:30 CET 2011
seven-wonders: Sun Nov 13 05:44:30 CET 2011
vlc: Sun Nov 13 20:38:32 CET 2011
kayaking: Sun Nov 13 23:37:49 CET 2011
pan-american-highway: Mon Nov 14 21:58:27 CET 2011
afghanistan: Mon Nov 14 22:06:29 CET 2011
aruba: Wed Nov 16 20:25:53 CET 2011
carry-on: Fri Nov 18 00:17:44 CET 2011
dominican-republic: Fri Nov 18 03:05:37 CET 2011
the-hippie-trail: Sat Nov 19 19:29:33 CET 2011
chinese-new-year: Sun Nov 20 04:59:39 CET 2011
boracay: Sun Nov 20 04:59:39 CET 2011
orange-new-south-wales: Sun Nov 20 20:45:51 CET 2011
southeastern-europe: Mon Nov 21 21:30:46 CET 2011
gva: Tue Nov 22 13:08:18 CET 2011
compensation: Tue Nov 22 13:08:18 CET 2011
greyhound: Tue Nov 22 20:19:30 CET 2011
uluru: Tue Nov 22 21:34:59 CET 2011
northern-territory: Tue Nov 22 21:34:59 CET 2011
russian-citizens: Wed Nov 23 00:44:34 CET 2011
doh: Wed Nov 23 05:56:54 CET 2011
qatar: Wed Nov 23 05:56:54 CET 2011
saarbrucken: Wed Nov 23 12:23:20 CET 2011
hhn: Wed Nov 23 12:23:20 CET 2011
brisbane: Wed Nov 23 12:48:00 CET 2011
sicily: Thu Nov 24 17:30:02 CET 2011
prostitution: Fri Nov 25 14:44:36 CET 2011
amtrak: Mon Nov 28 16:06:41 CET 2011
california-zephyr: Mon Nov 28 16:06:41 CET 2011
czech-airlines: Mon Nov 28 20:07:06 CET 2011
lebanon: Mon Nov 28 21:49:30 CET 2011
tlv: Tue Nov 29 15:09:58 CET 2011
lcy: Tue Nov 29 17:21:43 CET 2011
docklands: Tue Nov 29 17:21:43 CET 2011
merano: Tue Nov 29 22:02:57 CET 2011
bitcoin: Wed Nov 30 01:45:10 CET 2011
verona: Wed Nov 30 04:10:52 CET 2011
airbus: Wed Nov 30 09:56:41 CET 2011
new-south-wales: Wed Nov 30 11:10:16 CET 2011
german-citizens: Wed Nov 30 11:56:23 CET 2011
tromso: Wed Nov 30 15:23:58 CET 2011
united-kingdom: Thu Dec 01 16:51:38 CET 2011
amusement-parks: Thu Dec 01 21:24:28 CET 2011
van-turkey: Thu Dec 01 22:11:24 CET 2011
kurdistan: Thu Dec 01 22:11:24 CET 2011
facebook: Thu Dec 01 22:29:23 CET 2011
ios: Thu Dec 01 22:29:23 CET 2011
app: Thu Dec 01 22:29:23 CET 2011
notifications: Thu Dec 01 22:29:23 CET 2011
basel: Fri Dec 02 17:39:22 CET 2011
kaliningrad: Fri Dec 02 23:59:51 CET 2011
bethlehem: Sat Dec 03 16:35:39 CET 2011
west-bank: Sat Dec 03 16:35:39 CET 2011
bratislava: Sun Dec 04 16:08:57 CET 2011
slovakia: Sun Dec 04 16:08:57 CET 2011
monasteries: Sun Dec 04 22:48:39 CET 2011
temples: Sun Dec 04 22:48:39 CET 2011
romme: Sun Dec 04 22:55:56 CET 2011
cairns: Sun Dec 04 23:56:25 CET 2011
search-engines: Sun Dec 04 23:57:05 CET 2011
trondheim: Mon Dec 05 20:16:29 CET 2011
french-citizens: Wed Dec 07 14:54:55 CET 2011
greenland: Wed Dec 07 15:51:14 CET 2011
cancun: Wed Dec 07 17:48:00 CET 2011
miami: Wed Dec 07 17:48:00 CET 2011
aep: Sat Dec 10 10:52:07 CET 2011
eze: Sat Dec 10 10:52:07 CET 2011
discounts: Mon Dec 12 05:27:59 CET 2011
global-entry: Mon Dec 12 06:56:58 CET 2011
mga: Mon Dec 12 07:10:39 CET 2011
silk-road: Mon Dec 12 16:58:21 CET 2011
antigua-and-barbuda: Tue Dec 13 01:48:50 CET 2011
fukuoka: Tue Dec 13 07:44:39 CET 2011
equator: Tue Dec 13 10:05:44 CET 2011
micronations: Wed Dec 14 01:52:55 CET 2011
florida-keys: Wed Dec 14 01:52:55 CET 2011
new-delhi: Wed Dec 14 07:36:19 CET 2011
south-pole: Wed Dec 14 23:02:04 CET 2011
sailing: Wed Dec 14 23:10:38 CET 2011
learning: Wed Dec 14 23:10:38 CET 2011
odd-destinations: Wed Dec 14 23:54:31 CET 2011
cuenca: Fri Dec 16 09:11:19 CET 2011
quito: Fri Dec 16 09:11:19 CET 2011
kenya: Fri Dec 16 13:42:16 CET 2011
north-korea: Fri Dec 16 23:57:37 CET 2011
pyrenees: Sat Dec 17 18:28:03 CET 2011
chechnya: Sat Dec 17 20:30:44 CET 2011
offroad: Sun Dec 18 13:38:32 CET 2011
brazil-citizens: Sun Dec 18 22:47:22 CET 2011
chiang-mai: Mon Dec 19 01:58:18 CET 2011
animal-riding: Mon Dec 19 03:15:49 CET 2011
khao-sok: Mon Dec 19 03:15:49 CET 2011
ethical-travel: Mon Dec 19 03:15:49 CET 2011
la-paz: Mon Dec 19 03:16:52 CET 2011
prisons: Mon Dec 19 03:16:52 CET 2011
luxury: Mon Dec 19 04:20:16 CET 2011
north-africa: Mon Dec 19 04:20:16 CET 2011
resorts: Mon Dec 19 04:20:16 CET 2011
lake-titicaca: Mon Dec 19 18:11:05 CET 2011
sweden-citizens: Tue Dec 20 04:13:29 CET 2011
libya: Tue Dec 20 04:13:29 CET 2011
easter-island: Tue Dec 20 10:08:54 CET 2011
christmas-island: Tue Dec 20 13:14:12 CET 2011
ruins: Tue Dec 20 13:59:33 CET 2011
polish-citizens: Tue Dec 20 22:34:48 CET 2011
roraima: Wed Dec 21 02:06:59 CET 2011
caracas: Wed Dec 21 02:06:59 CET 2011
entertainment: Wed Dec 21 04:14:21 CET 2011
carnaval: Wed Dec 21 09:32:40 CET 2011
carnival-mardi-gras: Wed Dec 21 09:36:38 CET 2011
low-cost-carriers: Thu Dec 22 14:56:33 CET 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a new tool to show which tags have tag wiki excerpts and which do not.

It's a Google Chrome User Script. You might know these as Greasemonkey scripts if you are a Firefox user.

1. [Download it from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/3689922).
2. Open your "extensions" tab.
3. Drag the extension from the download folder and drop it on the extensions tab.
4. Load any page from travel.stackexchange.com, including meta. (It won't affect a page that was loaded before you install the extension.)

---

Screenshot:
[image: Extension screenshot]