# How to submit ideas for our "coming soon" blog?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, blog

[A few of us are playing around with the Stack Exchange APIs](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/420/do-we-need-tools-to-make-our-site-better) which led me to ask a question on webapps.SE which led me to play around a bit more with webapps.SE and I came across this great crossover question:

> [**What are the best travel web apps/sites? [closed]**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/what-are-the-best-travel-web-apps-sites)

Well OK it turned out to be closed for various not invalid reasons but the point of crossover questions with the many other SE sites is still valid.

As is the reason for this post, since each time we find something of interest like this we can't really make a question or a meta question about it but we still want to share it among our contributors.

Since [we're on the verge of starting an SE blog](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/who-wants-to-be-the-travel-stack-exchange-blogger) the obvious answer is "stick that stuff in the blog".

So what's the best way to suggest things for the blog?

- A meta post for each tidbit?
- A meta post each week asking for stuff?
- A shared file on Google docs or Evernote or something?
- Email [Mark Mayo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) directly?
- *Other*?

Comment: We should create our on webapp for that ;)

Comment: I personally think keeping it on the site is best...a meta thread should work fine. If it's updated regularly, it should stay near the top of the "newest" questions list. But maybe just one thread that has one blog post idea per answer, and then people can vote based on whether they'd like to read a post about that topic?

Comment: How about one meta "question" per blog post and one meta "answer" per idea then? The "question" can include either the intended publication date or "issue number"...

Comment: **PING!** lots of upvotes, no answers? ...

Answer (score 4):

My idea is create a simple web app in Google App Engine, to submit the idea.

This should be the basic flow:

1. Mark Mayo creates topic "What are the best travel web apps/sites?" in the GAE
2. A person submit the URL to the Google App Engine.
3. Every 2 days, the GAE will run a simple batch job to notify Mark Mayo ( for example) if there are new submissions using email.
4. Mary Mayo visits the URL to check the idea and validates the URL.
5. (a) All validated URL will be imported to an RSS XML. 
       The blog shows all recommended and filtered URL by loading this RSS XML and display it to public. or

   (b) Alternatively, Mark Mayo can just copy and paste to the blog.

I can help to create some prototype. :)

Comment: Vmatm and I feel left out. :'(

Answer (score 3):

I think making one meta question for the entire thing and have people post ideas as answers would be completely fine. The comments would function well for discussion of whether it's a  good idea or not. And people can upvote the ideas they find the most interesting. We can edit old answers that have been written about to indicate them as status-complete.

Is the concept that people can propose their ideas to find out if there is interest and then write them if there is? Or is it to propose ideas for the blog writers to write about?

Travel is such a huge topic that so many people are interested in, there are literally thousands of topics I can think of to write about. I'm sure that as the site grows writing for the blog will become pretty popular.

Comment: Would we have one meta question per coming blog post?