# Topic Challenge - call for topics

Tags: discussion, events

As per https://judaism.stackexchange.com/, a "Topic Challenge" appearing every so often to challenge people to ask questions might be a good idea.  Are you going somewhere soon? Do you have a topic you'd like to ramp up your tag badges on?  Suggest a topic in the answers below, and vote them up or down, and on the weekend we may select one and make it the topic challenge.

Comment: I've created events into early January now, as often indicated below.  For the full list, check http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the events of your choice (heck, all of them, the more quality questions the better!)

Answer (score 7):

### The Tiny Countries

- Andorra
- Brunei
- Liechtenstein
- Luxembourg
- Monaco
- San Marino
- Malta
- Vatican City
- Nauru
- Tuvalu
- Marshall Islands
- St. Kitts & Nevis
- Maldives
- Grenada
- St. Lucia
- Palau
- Seychelles
- Antigua & Barbuda
- Barbados
- St. Vincent & Grenadines
- Micronesia

Comment: (Don't be shy to add what I left out)

Comment: I really like this proposal and I'm waiting for hundreds of Liechtenstein questions!

Comment: Don't have meta-edit privileges yet, so here are some tiny additions: Nauru, Tuvalu, Marshall Islands, St. Kitts & Nevis, Maldives, Grenada, Andorra, St. Lucia, Palau, Seychelles, Antigua & Barbuda, Barbados, St. Vincent & Grenadines, Micronesia.  Long long ago I played an Apple II game called Andorra...anyone remember that?

Comment: I don't know the game Andorra, but I do remember the bus ride from the heat of spain into the falling snow, and eating snails in a very authentic bar.

Comment: I did a couple of these then decided if we were going to do it, we'd be better off just doing every blasted country.  Perhaps I'll start creating events on the national days of countries around the world...

Comment: @MarkMayo +1 for the national days idea!! But I don't understand the first part of your comment at all.

Comment: Oh, I meant I made events for them, but there were so many of them that my mind thought it'd just be easier to go through an alphabetical list of countries, and that seemed a little pointless.  National days is good tho, I might start a community wiki idea for it.

Comment: here we go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Day

Comment: You don't need to go through them. The whole point of the suggestion was that these countries are so tiny that they can share an event for all tiny countries rather than have one separate event for each tiny country (-:

Answer (score 6):

### World Heritage Sites

I would like to see some great questions about [world heritage sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Heritage_Site).

Comment: Yes we should even have a tag for it... maybe we already do have [tag:unesco]?

Comment: Yes maybe the unesco tag can be used for that or we make a new dedicated tag.

Comment: This will be December 27th.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Answer (score 5):

**Volunteering**

Where can we go and do stuff like helping out on farms in Guatemala and tsunami cleanup in Japan etc...

Comment: Not sure whether that would fall under this or Immigration.SE

Comment: I didn't have to immigrate to Japan to do tsunami cleanup six months ago. I didn't need a special visa either.

Comment: Dec 28th event.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Answer (score 5):

### Boost single-use tags

How about an event where we go through our oldest tags that are only applied to a single question and think of at least one more question for each of them?

As a bonus any tags that are too hard to think of more questions for should possibly be discarded or made synonyms of broader tags that would cover them.

Comment: if you find some, we can do it!

Comment: Rofl and I have been hacking the API. It's fun. I believe most of us here have some coding in our backgrounds so you should try it too (-:

Comment: if I only had the time ;) My coding time is going into like 3 other side projects at present.  Maybe over the Christmas break.

Comment: Don't worry I've taken to [suggesting tools project ideas](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/580/140) over on the Meta question about them.

Answer (score 4):

### Long-distance train journeys

I would like to see some more great questions about traveling long distances with a train, for example the Siberian railway.

Comment: 29th of December event :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Answer (score 4):

### Ambiguous place names

This will have the added benefit of helping us fix our policy of how to pick the wording for tags when there's more than one Georgia or Korea in the world.

- [Victoria, Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_%28Australia%29)
- [Victoria, BC, Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria,_British_Columbia)
- [Victoria, Seychelles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria,_Seychelles)

---

- [Usa, Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usa_Shrine)

---

- [New York City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City)
- [New York State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York)

---

- [Washington, DC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.)
- [Washington State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.)

---

- [Montana, Bulgaria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montana,_Bulgaria)
- [Montana State, US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montana)

---

- [Perth, Scotland](http://wikitravel.org/en/Perth_%28Scotland%29)
- [Perth, Australia](http://wikitravel.org/en/Perth)

*(Please add any others you can think of, but only of course if they have something to offer tourists/travellers.)*

Comment: not sure how to do this as an event...

Comment: How to do this as an event: Hey everybody welcome to our ambiguous place name event. So think of some names that refer to more than one travel-worthy place (or check our list) and ask good travel related questions about them! You may have to create some new tags but don't worry if you can't since our mods are also participating and can add them, rename them, and clean them up for you. Go!

Answer (score 3):

### Naturism

I would like to see some great questions about [naturism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturism) travel.

Comment: I for one welcome our naked URL overlords!

Comment: Just so we are clear from the onset: no pictures.

Comment: I already hoped that I can finally show off my holiday pictures :(

Comment: Just so we are even clearer from the onset: no pictures with wobbly bits.

Comment: Naked URL day??

Comment: 30th of December event

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Answer (score 3):

**River Amazon / River Nile trail**

Everything about travelling down the Amazon / Nile from source to where they terminate at sea.

Comment: January 2nd event.  Don't forget to register for the event to remind yourself!

Answer (score 3):

**Route 66**

Towns and places worth visiting along [US Route 66](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Route_66).

Comment: January 1st event.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Answer (score 3):

## Difficult Places and How To See Them

I mean genuinely difficult for the average traveler, and how to see them without breaking any laws.

For example, visitors to Lascaux are now shunted to a replica, but perhaps it is possible to visit the actual caves by volunteering in the cleanup & restoration effort?

Another example is the stairway of the Washington Monument. It was not publicized, but there were occasional tours where you could ride up on the elevator and descend via the stairs. Unfortunately, that has been discontinued owing to vandalism of the commemorative stones in the stairwell, but at the time when it was an option it would have been a candidate for this category.

Or climbing the Great Pyramid, which used to be illegal but easy to do with a bribe. In more recent years there has been a crackdown on the acceptance of these bribes owing to some climbers falling to their death. But maybe there's a way to legally climb it, complete with safety equipment? I'd sure like to know.

Comment: I'm sure you know but we have the [tag:adventure] and [tag:extreme-tourism] tags that will cover some such questions, but maybe not ones like the Washington monument one.

Comment: Yeah, the Pyramid example could fall under those tags, but the other two not so much. They're more about hidden places than extreeeem adventurrrrrrzzzz.  :D

Comment: please don't ever climb the pyramids, or any other historical monument. You'll get a great photo, but you WILL cause damage to the monument.

Comment: Event for December 31st has  been created

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule - don't forget to register for the event!

Comment: @Mark When I say safety equipment I mean safety for me and for the pyramid. The whole point of looking for *legal* ways to access these difficult places is to make sure that they're being visited in a *responsible* way. I.e. I'm looking for "white hat" travel hacks, not "black hat".

Comment: Cool, it was hard to tell from your original statement, but my comment was for anyone that might read it and consider bribing as a result :)  I couldn't believe how many people (where cameras were banned) would not only use their flash (causing light damage) but then reach out and touch the paintings on tunnel walls!

Comment: If pyramid climbing is what you crave, I highly recommend [the one in the middle of Tiranë, Albania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enver_Hoxha_Mausoleum). It seems you can damage that monument to your heart's delight.

Answer (score 2):

### Pan-American Highway

I would like to see some great questions about the [Pan-American Highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-American_Highway).

Answer (score 2):

### Ecotourism

I would like to see some great questions about [ecotourism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecotourism).

Answer (score 2):

### Couch surfing

I would like to see some more great questions about couch surfing.

Comment: Recommend that for tagging purposes we use a more generic term like accommodation-exchange or free-accomodation or homestay, since "'CouchSurfing' and 'CouchSurfer' are registered and unregistered service marks of CouchSurfing International."

Comment: Homestay is a totally different tradition to the likes of hospitality club and couch surfing, I don't recommend overloading that term.

Answer (score 1):

## **The Caucasus**

**South Caucasus**

Georgia, Armenia, Azerbaijan

Plus the disputed territories, rebel provinces, and exclaves

Abkhazia, Nagorno Karabakh, Naxchivan, South Ossetia

**North Caucasus**

Dagestan, Ingushetia, Chechnya, etc

Answer (score 1):

### Roadtrip

I would like to see some more great questions about roadtrips. We have a lot questions for Europe, but Asia or the Americas is not covered yet.

Comment: Australia is also a great place for road trips. I'm not sure about Asia though. I don't think it's really done in the rich countries or the developing countries for different reasons. But I'd like to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Trekking

I would like to seem some great questions about trekking.

Comment: You already seem like a great trekking question to me! d-;

Answer (score 0):

### Disaster tourism

I would like to see some great questions about [disaster tourism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_tourism).

Comment: You mean voyeuristic or volunteering to fix up afterwards?

Comment: In this case I'm rater referring to voyeuristic or to put it in a nice word education.

Comment: Then my experience helping out in Northern Japan this summer will not be much use...

Comment: We can create a second topic proposal for that

Comment: btw just to clarify I don't not really support such kind of tourism but I think it is an interesting topic to think about.

Comment: You don't? What about visiting Chernobyl (like I did in 2008)? It opens your eyes to the dangers of human error, rushing projects and the impact we can have on our world.  I'd recommend it to anyone!

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to say!

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/is-tourism-beneficial-to-the-economies-of-places-affected-by-natural-disasters isn't exactly disaster tourism, but it's related. Out of curiosity, does Hiroshima (which I haven't been to) count as disaster tourism?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see questions about [Geoglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoglyph).

Comment: You mean there are more? (-:

Comment: I hope so. I think in China for example.

Comment: lots more!  You could even argue that the Pyramids represent the constellation of Orion...

Comment: Bah the pyramids are not a glyph. I guess you could expand it to stuff that might have some interpretation when viewed from the sky.